# How to better navigate a large project in the Visual J++ 6.0 IDE

Tags: java, ide, visualj#, j++

So I have this extremely large old code base written in J++ that I need to go into at times to update/fix certain things.  Much has been migrated to newer languages, but the old code is still being used.  I am just getting into the code base and am finding it very difficult to figure it out with the Visual J++ 6.0 IDE.  I am used to newer visual studio .net IDE's and even Netbeans java IDE has much better navigation features.

My biggest headache is not having a "find all references" type of functionality and being able to jump to a function definition (outside of the class I am in), see what it is expecting for variable types, jump to a class declaration, etc.  There seems to be limited support by using the Class View to jump to the definition of the object within that class, but jumping to THAT classes declaration or to an outside function definition seems to be beyond it.  Not to mention the windows arent tabbed so it gets horribly cluttered.  Intellisense is very limited, etc.

I know it is old, but some of the things seems like it would/should have been supported.

**I guess I am looking for any tips, maybe possible tools that can help make navigating and learning this code base less painful.  I am using windows explorer to search all the files in the project, because it doesnt even have a find in files.**

Comment: Wonder if you'd be able to load up the project into Eclipse?

Comment: There are plenty of editors that can do a file search (for example [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Answer (score 1):

We had same problem.
I resolved that by making a new ANT project (Own compile and clean etc. tasks) for Netbeans.
I had to do it this way, because I couldn't get the Netbeans build system to work correctly with the added J++ compiler.
I then added new JDK target so that Netbeans would find all the required MS classes (ZIP files from J++ install)

After all this I had a compilation environment where I could use all the strengths of Netbeans but still was able to compile with the J++ compiler (VJC).

We use it still to maintain our legacy platform. And this has made the codebase much easier to handle as we can use refactoring and all the other automated tools from Netbeans.

This way we could put the sources under SVN instead of the hideous SourceSafe where they were before.

So If this sounds like an idea you would want to try just ask and I will provide you the pointers how to get it done.

NOTE! This doesn't work that well if you have used the GUI builder stuff, although we managed to make an experimental project where we had the ANT+Netbeans project and J++ project which shared the same sources.